# Having separate files for actions but using one store in Mobx. (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, mobx, mobx-react

i was thinking of using multiples files to store my `actions` in `Mobx`. `React-Native`

something like this:

```
//store.js

export default class Store {
   @observable property = "change me";
}

//loginActions.js

export default class LoginActions {
   @action changeProperty() {
        //how can i get a reference to the store?
        store.property = "value changed"
   }
}

//LoginComponent.js
@inject(["store"])
@observer
export default class LoginComponent extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        //how can i reference my action here to do something like
        LoginAction.changeProperty()
    }

    render(){
        return(
            //i should have a reference to my store here
            <Text>{this.props.store.property}<Text/>
        )
    }
}
```

i want to know if it is possible or if it has any downside to it?
how can i pass the store reference to the actions file and still be able to change its values?
how can i call the actions from my react components?

Answer (score 0):

by extending the Store class to the LoginActions class like this:

```
export class Store {
       @observable property = "change me";
    }

//loginActions.js

export class LoginActions extends Store {
   constructor(property) {
      super()
   }
   @action changeProperty() {
        this.property = "value changed"
   }
}
```